# logic for constructing thumbnail in 3 columns for each row

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

This might sound elementary, but I have N 'Hosts' and I'm trying to figure out the logic so that I can create rows of panels with 3 Hosts in each panel. A host is just a pic. Below is my code but I'm not sure how to set it up. Ex. 3 pics would be one row with 1 panel and 3 columns all containing 1 pic each. Or 5 pics/hosts would have 2 rows/panels with 3 pics in the first row and 2 pics in the second row. etc, etc.

Here is my code

```
foreach (var host in Model.Hosts) {
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-sm-4">thumbnail pic/host</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">thumbnail pic/host</div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">thumbnail pic/host</div>
      </div>
</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the razor `@:` to break out of the c# loop code and render a 'new row'

```cs
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Hosts.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0 && i % 3 == 0)
            {
                // close the row div's and start new ones
                @:</div></div><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body">
            }
            <div class="col-sm-4">@Model.Hosts[i].SomeProperty</div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Note if `Hosts` is not `IList<T>`, then use declare a variable - `@{ int i = 0; }` - and increment it and the end of each iteration - `i++;` - for use in the `if` block

Comment: what is the @: symbol? And what does it do?

Comment: It breaks of of the c# code block and allows you to start new html content. For a further explanation, refer [ASP.NET MVC 3: Razor’s @: and <text> syntax](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax)